# Static content from my local django server loads incredibly slowly when using an domain aliased to localhost, vs. localhost itself

Tags: python, django, macos, django-views

I've added the domain to my /etc/hosts/ file, and my site resolves, however static content is loading *painfully* slow. I'm talking 30 seconds for a page that normally takes 0.8s from localhost. I have no idea why this is, and it's killing my workflow. I actually formatted my machine to see if that would resolve but still no luck. This is on the latest version of Mac OS X.

So, http://localhost:8000 is great, very fast, while http://mydomain.com:8000 is painfully slow.

I can't use localhost or 127.0.0.1 because it's an application that uses Facebook connect, and they recently stopped allowing both of those as valid URLs for applications.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1   mydomain.com
```

Comment: You add aliases to the right of a hosts-entry. *Maybe* this is relevant for some lookup. Also, *maybe* some sort of IPv6-related fallback affects you? Tried adding it to the `::1`-entry as well? You can also try using `127.0.0.2` instead (or any other address in 127.0.0.0/8) (These are all more or less guesses)

Comment: As @plundra says, the first non-comment line of your hosts file should look like `127.0.0.1   localhost mydomain.com`. Run `host mydomain.com` from a terminal prompt to see if it is configured correctly.

Comment: And, on OS X, you won't be able to use 127.0.0.2 (or any other address in that block) unless you activate it first with `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up`.

Comment: The host command doesn't resolve properly, but ping/traceroute does, if that helps. Host mydomain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Answer (score 1):

I'd test with the SimpleHTTPServer to see if the problem is related to Django or not:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: The image files load instantly that way, so I'd imagine it is.